# springMvc and hibernate persistence

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am getting error on save button when i tried to click on save to insert data in database.
I don't know which library is missing .... still i included all the spring and hibernate persistence libraries.
anyone can please help me....

```
HTTP Status 500 - 

The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception:

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested     exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:     javax.persistence.Persistence.getPersistenceUtil()Ljavax/persistence/PersistenceUtil;
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:839)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

root cause 

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Persistence.getPersistenceUtil()Ljavax/persistence/PersistenceUtil;
org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.isReachable(JPATraversableResolver.java:62)
org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver.isReachable(DefaultTraversableResolver.java:94)
org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.SingleThreadCachedTraversableResolver.isReachable(SingleThreadCachedTraversableResolver.java:47)
org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.isValidationRequired(ValidatorImpl.java:757)
org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:324)
org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForRedefinedDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:273)
org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:256)
org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:210)
org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:119)
org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter.validate(SpringValidatorAdapter.java:86)
org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.validate(DataBinder.java:692)
org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.doBind(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:807)
org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveHandlerArguments(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:359)
org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:171)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)


note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.20 logs.

Apache Tomcat/6.0.20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a missing library. It's a version mismatch. It appears that your JPA api version is incompatible with your Hibernate version.

A quick comparison of `javax.persistence.Persistence` between [Java EE 5](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Persistence.html) and [Java EE 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Persistence.html) plainly shows that the `getPersistenceUtil()` method was added in 6. If you're stuck with a Java EE 5 server/library, then you'll have to use an appropriate version of Hibernate or whatever Hibernate jar is looking for that method. It seems to be coming out of hibernate-validator.

Comment: i am using hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar and hibernate version is 3.3.2.GA then where mismatch

Comment: I'd check your classpath and find any other `javax.persistence.Persistence` classes that may be interfering because hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar [appears to have the method](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api/1.0.0.Final/javax/persistence/Persistence.java?av=f) that your error says is missing.

Comment: Hmm, I suppose there's also a slight possibility that you have some crazy class-loading going on and that you have two versions of `PersistenceUtil` being loaded, which would also account for the error.

Comment: i had included javax.persistence_2.0.0 but i removed it from classpath still it giving me same error....   now included jars are ejb3-persistence-1.0.2.GA.jar,hibernate-validator-4.1.0.Final.jar,javax.validation-1.0.0.GA.jar

Comment: Thanks Ryan ..my problem got solved ....actually i was pesisted because of ejb3-persistence-1.0.2.GA....so i removed and error disappeared.........thanks a lot